# Install MySQL and PHP and Apache on Raspberry pi

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I need to install MySQL on my Raspberry Pi but I am having some issues doing it. 
After some research, I saw that I need to have Apache and PHP installed to be able to have MySQL after, otherwise it wouldn't work.

I followed this tutorial : https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-web-server-on-the-raspberry-pi/ but when I arrive to the step 4 which is install php, it doesn't work.

When I write in the terminal : `sudo apt-get install php5` it says

> Package 'php5' has no installation candidate

if I write `sudo apt-get install php`, it runs it but I don't know how to link it with nginx after that, as I can't follow the tutorial (not the same command)

Would you have some advice ? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to use nginx or Apache as web server? And which PHP Version do you want to use? PHP5 is the old version, PHP7 the new one.

Comment: The tutorial asks you to install `php5-fpm` not just `php5`, have you tried that? `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql`

Comment: TK either actually, I just need MySQL to work, I don't really know which one is best to do that. I want to use PHP7
I have followed different tutorials and tried the different options but it always leads me to that. Maybe it is because I want to use php7 but I am not sure how to adapt the code for that

Comment: Rob Forrest : yes I tried that too, it gives me the same return, that the package is not available

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I think you have to build it from source if the package is not available. Look at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and download the source.

It seems to me that you are confused. It is not true you need Apache and PHP installed to have MySQL. What exactly do you need? Must it be MySQL? Do you need a full web stack?

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: Yes I am completely lost on that. 
I just need to use MySQL ! So you are saying that I don't need php for that ?

I don't know if it connected to what you are saying but when I type : MySQL -p -u root
It asks for a password  and denied access

Comment: Ok, I am not the Web or Database guru, but I think once I went through the same, installing a DB. It looks that is already installed as is asking you for a password, I think you have to set up a user for the database or configure MySql to allow you to log in. I think it is more a first-time configuration issue (root user, new user, permissions, etc). What if you remove -p?. I remember there is a configuration file to specify the usage of password or not and to allow local connections to the DB.

Comment: It may be installed yes but I still don't know how I can access the configuration for that. Do I have to type something on the terminal to create a password ?
If I remove the -p, it says : "ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' "

Comment: Ok I thinks it works ! It opens the MariaDB monitor if I put root as a password.
Do you think it is what I need ?

Comment: Sure, once in the monitor or DB console you can admin your DB (adding users and handling tables)